# What helps (justification) to decide cut score/cutoff points for 5-point likert scale?

Tags: likert, scales, measurement

I am wondering what are the factors involved in deciding the cutoff value / cut score for a 5-point Likert scale from:

```
1 = Not ready at all 
2 = Not ready
3 = Moderately ready 
4 = Ready
5 = Highly ready
```

Is it proper for the cut score (in mean value) to be as such if i want it in 3 categories:

```
Below 2 = Not ready 
2 - 4 = Ready 
Above 4 = Highly ready
```

And if yes, how do I justify my decision? Are there any references or empirical ways to help decide? I was told that I could justify that the inherent meaning of the scale helps to make such decision - especially using the information embodied in the numerical value - which expert said that?

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to reduce the number of categories. One case where it might be is if one level (or more than one) has almost no observations. 

Usually best to leave it as 5 points.

Comment: Unfortunately, because my write-up will be complemented with quantified qualitative data (also using mean) with 3 categories of decriptors, I have not choice but to collapse them - however, I would need a strong valid reason to put them in the mentioned cut score.  I wonder what would be a strong one?

Comment: Can you give some more detail of what you are trying to match to? How can qualitative data have a mean? 

One thing is to try different collapsings (if that's a word) and compare results.

Comment: I can compare my results of my qualitative data (document analysis eg) as they are not using the same scale and they consist of different samples - however, I believe they could be used to support my survey - that's the reason I had to collapse the likert-type responses into three but of course then, the next question is how?

Comment: There is no reason, in theory, why a 5 category scale cannot support a 3 category scale.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate further on that?

Comment: The site doesn't like these long discussions, so this will have to be my last comment here, but, e.g. a 5x3 crosstabs is certainly feasible if the sample size is large enough (e.g. over about 100).

Given that the scales don't match, anyway, there's little to be gained by collapsing yours, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am a newbie, did not know much about the rules but thank you for trying to explain. But honestly, the burning question now is how does one (with empirical prove) decide on cut score for likert scale.  Thanks again.

Comment: I know of no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

From a theoretical perspective, the cutoff points for a Likert scale item are completely arbitrary. The tradition in psychology for scales like yours is to use something [between 5 to 7 items](https://meridian.allenpress.com/jgme/article/5/4/541/34037/Analyzing-and-Interpreting-Data-From-LikertType), but there is no saying that a 3-point scale or a 5-point scale can have complete superiority over one another (indeed, my field uses a lot of binary tests simply because literacy measures often don't require that much flexibility). One does have to make certain tradeoffs between:

- The item having too few levels that it doesn't capture the construct of interest well (e.g. "Are you happy?" with just a binary response probably isn't effective).
- Having too many levels that the the levels effectively become redundant (e.g. the same question rated on a scale from 1 to 200 is similarly weird to do).

On the data side of things, there are certain features about the number of items which lend itself to nice properties. If a scale consists of binary items, then answering them becomes simpler and you can use them quite easily for things like by-trial logistic regressions. However, because of the lack of variance in such an item (it can only be equal to $0$ or $1$), increasing the number of items allows one to increase the level of estimable variance per item, and it may force choices which the user does not meaningfully report (they can also be a pain if you want to estimate factor-analysis based reliability with several items). [At least one study](http://doi.apa.org/getdoi.cfm?doi=10.1037/pas0000648) has shown that using more than six items generally doesn't improve responses and a smaller number of response levels may have a negative affect on responses as well. However, this isn't a law and would vary by research context.

The real answer becomes whether or not the levels properly account for the construct of interest both per-item and as a whole (if there are many items like it). Much of this can be answered by either pilot testing the data with multiple forms, then see which has better bandwidth-fidelity, or using well-validated tests, which have across-study validity and reliability. Following up testing with questionnaires about the measures for the subjects to discuss can also be a helpful option to get directly into the minds of the users. McDonald's book on test theory has some great parts in the initial three chapters about the rules of item construction, when levels become too simple/redundant, sample size effects, and how to think of the items in terms of a composite, so I put that book as a reference below for educational purposes.

**Above all, I must stress that reducing down levels post-hoc, after the study has already been conducted, is a terrible practice and should never be done.** I note that because your question/comments seems to indicate that this is what you will be doing, which makes little sense to do. This necessarily reduces the amount of variation in response *after* it has already been recorded. You also can't change what people have dictated in that moment to be their choice. You're effectively "reading their minds for them" by falsely changing their responses to something more/less strong than what it was. The fact that this was for a qualitative study makes the purpose of this even more uncertain.

##### References

- McDonald, R. P. (1999). Test theory: A unified treatment. Routledge.
- Simms, L. J., Zelazny, K., Williams, T. F., & Bernstein, L. (2019). Does the number of response options matter? Psychometric perspectives using personality questionnaire data. Psychological Assessment, 31(4), 557–566. https://doi.org/10.1037/pas0000648
- Sullivan, G. M., & Artino, A. R. (2013). Analyzing and interpreting data from likert-type scales. Journal of Graduate Medical Education, 5(4), 541–542. https://doi.org/10.4300/JGME-5-4-18